# How to str_detect a string that contains parentheses?

Tags: r, regex, string, dplyr

I am trying to do a string search for multiple strings on one column, but the script does not return strings that have parentheses.

```
a <-  c("Apple", "Facebook", "Google (1992)")
b <- c(1, 2, 3)

c <-  data.frame(a, b)

d <- c %>% 
  distinct(a) %>% 
  pull()

c %>% 
  filter(str_detect(a, paste(d, collapse = "|"))) %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  tally()
```

I want the last script to return "Apple", "Facebook", "Google (1992)", but it only returns the first two. Is there something I can add to the "collapse" argument to include strings with parentheses?

Comment: Is there a reason you do not use the `%in%` operator? The problem you are having is bc parentheses mean something special in regular expressions. They are typically used to capture a pattern.

Comment: I'm still new to R. How would I apply the %in% operator for the last script?

Comment: Since both your data variable is `a` and you have an environmental variable `a`, it is clearer to use the `.data.` and `.env` nouns that are imported into the `tidyverse` as part of the `rlang` package. This removes the ambiguity, but it would look something like `filter(.data$a %in% .env$a)`

Comment: just do `c %>% filter(a %in% d)`

Comment: You could even cut out the `d` step and do `c %>% filter(a %in% unique(a))` however within your example this will return every row.

Comment: @LMc in every example `c %>% filter(a %in% unique(a))` is just `c` if that was the goal, then there is no need to filter at all. I believe OP has another vector that is unique that they want to fifter from

Comment: Yup, I have another vector I am using to filter. But all the above is very interesting to know about. Thanks yall!

Comment: It is definitely not the most natural way if we use a vector to create patterns, only then to extract these very same patterns from the vector again. A non-regex element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Per the comments, you don't even need regex in this case. But for future reference:) As you may already know, parentheses have to be escaped in regular expressions. This is easy enough when you're specifying the pattern directly -- e.g., `str_detect(a, "Google \\(1992\\)")`. But it can be slightly trickier when the pattern is stored in a variable, as in your case. You can handle this as

```
library(stringr)

str_detect(a, paste(
  str_replace_all(d, c("\\(" = "\\\\(", "\\)" = "\\\\)")), 
  collapse = "|"
))
```

In the vector of replacements, we have to escape the parenthesis on the left side (`"\\("`). But on the right hand side, we have to escape the `"\"` -- we use `"\\\\"` to insert a literal `"\\"`.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `fixed` in `str_detect` by looping over the patterns and reducing it to a single logical vector

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
c %>% 
  filter(map(d, ~ str_detect(a, fixed(.x))) %>% reduce(`|`))
              a b
1         Apple 1
2      Facebook 2
3 Google (1992) 3
```